# What does sudo service do?

Tags: sudo

As far as I know and it seems that [other people have the same opinion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99736/how-do-i-stop-the-service-sudo#comment114408_99736) `sudo` is a command that executes something with administrative privileges.

However when I run `rcconf` I can see this line:

```
[*] sudo    Provide limited super user privileges to specific users
```

So what the point with this service? Or is this even a service?

Comment: This is what i found while searching google->[Sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: "This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users; for further information please refer to AddUsersHowto) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password." - That exactly what I said in my question.

Comment: The question is about the service, not the command

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Short answer

To revoke the 'cached' authentication actions of users on reboot. It's not a daemon, just a script run at boot time.

---

#### Extensive answer

By inspecting the init file `/etc/init.d/sudo` that 'starts the service', you can easily see what it's doing:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        # make sure privileges don't persist across reboots
        if [ -d /var/lib/sudo ]
        then
                find /var/lib/sudo -exec touch -t 198501010000 '{}' \;
        fi
        ;;
  stop|reload|restart|force-reload)
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

So, basically, it just touches some files in `/var/lib/sudo` on start of the system to have it a very old modification timestamp. As a result, the 'cached' granted authentication actions are revoked on the start of the service (which happens at boot).

Some more detail on the `/var/lib/sudo` directory and those time stamps, please? Well, from the mapage of [`sudo(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/sudo.8.html):

```
[...]
Once a user has been authenticated, a time stamp is updated and the
user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time
(15 minutes unless overridden in sudoers).
[...]
Since time stamp files live in the file system, they can outlive a
user's login session.  As a result, a user may be able to login, run a
command with sudo after authenticating, logout, login again, and run
sudo without authenticating so long as the time stamp file's
modification time is within 15 minutes (or whatever the timeout is set
to in sudoers).
[...]
/var/lib/sudo           Directory containing time stamps
```

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Answer (score 12):

The `sudo` service file exists to make sure that privileges called for don't stay after a reboot. Basically it guarantees that after rebooting, normal users that called for root permissions will stay as normal users.

---

**A detailed explanation about sudo**

All of the explanation below is to get all the information for everyone that reads this question and to then explain what the sudo file in the service folder is doing there.

When you install Ubuntu or any other distro that uses `sudo` the difference between being **root** and being a user that uses `sudo` for gaining "root like" privileges (Administrative or super user Privileges) is the following:

**As root**

- You are not asked for a password for each or all commands you run on a session
- Not all commands you execute will be logged by default
- The system assumes you know what you are doing (Reason why it does not ask for a password each time you execute a command)
- There is no second chance or last minute option if you make a mistake

**As sudo**

- You are asked for a password for each or all commands you run on a session. For example if you open a terminal and execute a command that needs administrative privileges it will ask the password once for that session until you close the terminal or logout. This varies depending on what command you use and where. It might ask once or multiple times.
- All commands you execute will be logged since you are actually asking for permission to use a super user privileged command.
- The system assumes you e asking for permission temporarily and the administrative right will be lent temporarily (Until you logout, close terminal, etc..)
- You have a last minute option to correct any mistake. This is done in the moment you get asked for the password.

### Why was SUDO Created

The creation of **SUDO** was done because in the past, using root created more problems than solutions. Users had all rights, which meant that if they did some spring cleanup and literally deleted the `/usr`, `/lib` and `/bin` folders (because they thought they did not needed them).. guess what would happen. Many problems in the past were because users did not know the power they had when using root. Basically they had root but did not understand Linux, the file system hierarchy, what files were important, etc.. (Something like having a ferrari and not knowing how to drive... in a highway!)

**SUDO** is also used by GUI apps (Like Update Manager) when they need temporary administrative privileges to do something. They only need it for a specific amount of commands (Typically 1) and then they go back to the user level privilege. This is to avoid having root privileges all the time and to avoid making a mistake if the user decides to remove some important part of the system.

Additionally it gives a better security because the root user comes disabled by default.

Last, if you have a Desktop PC or Server, you really do not want everyone to be root, nor to have all admin privileges. Very bad idea if your little sister or little brothers starts to wonder what would happen if `/boot` met <kbd>DEL</kbd> key. This is where `sudo` comes in to decrease the chance something bad happens.

### What does **Provide limited super user privileges to specific users** mean?

sudo user or sudoers actually have a configuration file that tells them how limited or opened the sudo command for a specific user is. The file `/etc/sudoers` has all information to limit or give access to a sudo user. By default it comes with access to everything, but you can configure or limit this as you wish.

For information on how to use the sudoers file type `man sudoers` in a terminal. For example the normal format is:

**USER HOST = COMMANDS**

For example `cyrex server1 = /bin/ls` will give the user cyrex in the host server1 access to run the ls command.

For example `cyrex server1 (root) = /bin/ls` will give the user cyrex in the host server1 access to run the ls command as root.

For example `cyrex ALL = /bin/ls` will give the user cyrex in all hosts access to run the ls command.

For example `cyrex ALL = ALL` will give the user cyrex in the all hosts access to run all commands.

For example `luis   ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /usr/bin/killall` will allow me to run sudo for the `kill` and `killall` commands as root without asking for a password.

[image]

Comment: He knows about what the sudo command does. The question is about a system service for sudo.

Comment: @gertvdijk - I had to first explain the basics, since not only him will be looking at this question. The last part includes the only reason I see for the sudo file in the service folder.

Comment: Thanks Luis Alvarado - The Wolver for such an extensive information and thanks for the funny modified [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/149/) referencing the `!!` bang bang operator, but what does the **service** (NOT the command) `sudo` does? It would be great if you could update your answer to really answer the question.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado-TheWolverine You've updated the answer now. I'll remove my downvote. However, I think it's an answer too extensive for such a specific question.

Comment: A little bit of overkill explaining all that for just a phrase in the end, but it answers my question ;)

Comment: +1 for the picture @LuisAlvarado-TheWolverine Great picture ;) You did it yourself? Let me guess.. Pinta

Comment: @Lucio no hehe. It's the famous sudo sandwich image from xkcd.com. Type in google "sudo sandwich", the first ones will be from xkcd.com

Comment: @LuisAlvarado-TheWolverine Haha, your right. It had been good that you respond me *yes, I did*.. Thanks