# can not paste or make new folder on file system directly with out gksudo nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, security, configuration

I have installed ubuntu 12.04, But I can not paste or make new folder in File system, however I can paste new files with gksudo nautilus, but how can i do directly without gksudo nautilus??

Comment: In what location(the path) are you trying to copy/create files/folders?

Answer (score 0):

You need [superuser(sudo)](https://askubuntu.com/a/228296/72576) privileges for creating(this implies pasting) files in locations other than your own home folder(`/home/$USER/`). [gksudo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) is just the graphical sudo, so you need to open graphical applications with `gksudo`.

So, if you want to create files/folders in directories such `/home/`(not `/home/$USER`), or `/` or any other directory than `/home/$USER/`, you will need to use `gksudo nautilus`.