# I am having trouble installing Retroarch?

Tags: ppa

This website is teaching me how to install retroarch.
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/install-retroarch-emulator-ppa-ubuntu/
I enter the first line in the terminal, the one that installs the PPA. 
"add-apt-repository ppa:hunter-kaller/ppa"
And in return, I get this:
"Error: must run as root"
I am quite confused. Help?

Answer (score 1):

All the commands mentioned should be run as root, you can do this by prefixing the commands with `sudo` - so you need to run these instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install retroarch libretro*
```

Sort of simple explaination of `sudo` [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/do-you-sudo-learn-the-basics/), more complicated one [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/228296/178596)
<sup>Please comment if you feel you have better examples.</sup>

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 and newer, it is better to use the new PPA "ppa:libretro/stable". (More info: http://www.libretro.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=2351)